# How Binding Index in Xaml when index name contain "[ ]" Special Characters

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding

I Write DateTemplate Binding Index, like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="VisitorCellTemplate">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding [[GroupName].[ItemName]]}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**[GroupName].[ItemName]** is index key.

I try write

> {Binding ['[Measures].[Visits]']}

but not able building.

Help Me! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Escapes for Property Path Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx#databinding_s) in this MSDN page

It explains that in general you can escape special characters by using the backslash `\` and that you need to use the carret `^` inside of the indexers `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: use a backslash `\` for any special character (look at this example: `{Binding Path=\[Maxe\], Mode=OneWay"]}` ), except if you are inside an indexer, and you should use the `^` symbol (for example, when you access an array: `{Binding Path=Names['^[Maxe^]'], Mode=OneWay"}` )

So in your case:

```
{Binding Path='\[Measures\].\[Visits\]'}
```